# Switching domain from HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, 301-redirect, https

I recently launched a new site on an existing domain, using new hosting. The previous site utilized HTTPS, the new site does not (just HTTP).

The problem I ran into is that Google currently has the site indexed as HTTPS.  The site is in WordPress, I've tried to 301 redirect HTTPS URLs to HTTP with `.htaccess` (placing rules above the WordPress rules), with no success. The HTTPS version displays the security warning of course (as there is no SSL certificate) and then a 404 if you go past that.

Here is what the `.htaccess` file currently looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I've tried other rules as well to redirect the traffic with no luck.

Additionally, Google Chrome still redirects `example.com` to `https://example.com`, no amount of clearing cache resolves this issue. All other browsers work fine, `www.example.com` works as expected in all browsers.

Has anyone else experienced these issues when moving a domain away from HTTPS?  Is there a standard way to notify Google of the change?

Comment: I suggest you put the effort you want to do in enabling https, not in trying to get it out. If your host doesn't allow for https, it's (IMO) a bad hoster and you should move.

Answer (score 11):

Why not get a free SSL certificate from Lets Encrypt, then your `https` will work.  Ride the horse in the direction it is going...

Comment: It's not only free but incredibly easy to install using their automated script. I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 5):

(Just a guess.)

If the old site used [HSTS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797), you have to wait the number of seconds that were specified in [`max-age`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797#section-6.1.1) until users that visited the HTTPS version can visit the HTTP version again.

(If HTTPS would still work, you could send the HSTS header and specify a very short `max-age`, and after most users visited again, stop sending the header, and then transition to HTTP.)

You could remove the domain from your browser’s HSTS Policy cache, but this would of course only help you, not your visitors (unless they do the same). In Chrome/Chromium, you should be able to access the cache under the address `chrome://net-internals/#hsts`; there you can delete your domain.¹

¹ I guess this doesn’t work if your domain is included in the [preload list](https://hstspreload.appspot.com/).

Answer (score 1):

> The HTTPS version displays the security warning of course (as there is no SSL certificate) and then a 404 if you go past that.

If you get a "security warning" that you are able to *bypass* then the *server* is listening on port 443 and there is a security certificate installed but for a different domain/hostname.

When you bypass this invalid certificate then the request is probably not reaching your website (Virtual Host) in a shared hosting environment, hence the 404.

There is no way for you to redirect the HTTPS request as it's not reaching your site.

The *only way* to resolve this is to install a valid SSL cert for your site.

> Additionally, Google Chrome still redirects `example.com` to `https://example.com`, no amount of clearing cache resolves this issue. All other browsers work fine, `www.example.com` works as expected in all browsers.

You should examine the network traffic in the Browser's object inspector - this should tell you exactly what mechanism (cache, HSTS, ?) is triggering the redirect - whether it even is a redirect (in the case of HSTS).